# Method orderBy does not exist - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, sql-order-by

How can i use the orderBy method with this script:

```
 public function getProposalByUser($userId)
{
    return ProposalModel::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->paginate(4)->orderBy('desc');
}
```

the script is to select the proposal where user have. and i want to arrange it for the top is newest. 
Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english..

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset Read up on how to achieve this. You're using them in the wrong order, and you're missing the `column` you're trying to order by on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return ProposalModel::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->orderBy('user_id', 'desc')->paginate(4);
```

Comment: aahhh.. its work.. i try your script, and i update like this:

return ProposalModel::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(4);

Comment: @José you should update your answer explaining what is wrong. timlewis had a good comment on the question.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the main problem is that you have used the methods in the wrong order.

```
public function getProposalByUser($userId)
{
    return ProposalModel::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->orderBy('desc')->paginate(4);
}
```

`paginate` actually returns the query results in a collection, and the collection doesn't have an `orderBy` method, so you can't chain it like you can with the other query builder methods.

Secondly, it looks like the orderBy method needs another argument, unless your entity actually does have a property called `'desc'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return ProposalModel::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->orderBy('created_date', 'desc')->paginate(4);
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.